# Get back matched value in list within subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT CUI,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CODE separator ';'),
    GROUP_CONCAT(SAB separator ';') 
    FROM umls.MRCONSO
WHERE CUI in (SELECT CUI FROM umls.MRCONSO WHERE code in ("10012271", "114480"))
GROUP BY CUI;
```

As part of my where clause I would like to "get" the code that has been matched on within the subquery in the `WHERE` clause and include that as part of the outer `SELECT` statement.

Currently my results would be something like:

| CUI | GROUP_CONCAT(CODE separator ';') | GROUP_CONCAT(CODE separator ';') |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C0002395 | R0121040;0000049799;10012271;D000544;NOCODE;D000544 | MDRJPN;MDRRUS;OMIM;NCI;ICD10CM;MDRHUN |
| C0002396 | R0121041;0000049780;114480;D000544;NOCODE;D000544 | MDRJPN;MDRRUS;OMIM;NCI;ICD10CM;MDRHUN |

But I would like:

| <MATCH_CODE | CUI | GROUP_CONCAT(CODE separator ';') | GROUP_CONCAT(CODE separator ';') |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10012271 | C0002395 | R0121040;0000049799;10012271;D000544;NOCODE;D000544 | MDRJPN;MDRRUS;OMIM;NCI;ICD10CM;MDRHUN |
| 114480 | C0002396 | R0121041;0000049780;114480;D000544;NOCODE;D000544 | MDRJPN;MDRRUS;OMIM;NCI;ICD10CM;MDRHUN |

Can someone help? I am not sure how to get back this code match in the sub query while also being able to access the codes from the outer query.

Comment: hmm, why aren't my tables rendering?

Comment: @eshirvana thanks!

Comment: Don't get used to use double quotes for string literals. Yes, sadly MySQL accepts that, but in SQL double quotes are usually for identifiers, such as column names. Should you ever use another DBMS (or future MySQL versions become more sane about this) you'll likely get an "invalid object name" error. Always use single quotes for string literals.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested this is the query I came up with for my use case - critiques welcome if anyone sees a more efficient way to do this :)

```
SELECT x.Code as MatchCode,
    m.CUI,
    GROUP_CONCAT(m.CODE separator '|') Codes, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(m.SAB separator '|') Sources
    FROM umls.MRCONSO m,
    (SELECT * FROM umls.MRCONSO WHERE code in ("104300", "114480")) x
WHERE x.cui = m.cui and x.sab in ("OMIM")
GROUP BY m.CUI;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want columns from more than one table, then you want `JOIN`.  You can use:

```
SELECT mx.Code as MatchCode, m.CUI,
       GROUP_CONCAT(m.CODE separator '|') as Codes, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(m.SAB separator '|') as Sources
FROM umls.MRCONSO m JOIN
     umls.MRCONSO mx
     ON x.cui = m.cui AND
        mx.code in ('104300', '114480') AND
        mx.sab in ('OMIM')
GROUP BY m.CUI, mx.Code;
```

Notes:

- This code uses proper `JOIN` syntax.
- The `GROUP BY` is consistent with the `SELECT`.
- Single quotes are the standard for strings in SQL.  I recommend them over double quotes.
- No subqueries are needed.